# Javascript causes Chromium to run out of memory

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, raspberry-pi, chromium

I have a chunk of code that causes a graph that monitors a graph to update periodically and is displayed with a raspberry pi, but the problem I'm having is because of the Pi's limited memory, Chromium dies because it run out of memory. I think this is because when the image updates, it saves the older images somewhere. I've tried using JS to delete the image and create a new one with an updated image, but it didn't work. I'm not too familiar with Javascript so I wasn't sure if I was making a rookie mistake or something. Here is the code:

```
<script type= "text/javascript">
var graph = "http://www.example.com";
function preload() 
{
    try
    {
        var buffer = new Image();
        buffer.src = graph;
        buffer.onload = function() 
        {
            while (1)
            {
                setTimeout(preload, 1000);
                document.getElementById('graph').src = buffer.src;
            }
        }
    }

    catch(err)
    {
        txt = "Error\n" + err.message;
        alert(txt);
    }
}   
preload()
</script>
```

And the HTML for the image is:

```
<img src= "http://www.example.com" id=graph width=1015 
    height=275 frameborder="0" onload="preload()" style="display: block; 
    margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" align="bottom"/>
```

Comment: You're queueing up an infinite number of events (`while(1){setTimeout(/*..*/);}`). That's what makes your browser run out of memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a vastly simplified script for you - your loop made no sense at all and there is no Ajax in your code

```
var graph = "https://zabbix.tulsahpc.org/signage/sign.png",tId;
window.onload=function() {
  tId=setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById('graph').src = graph+new Date().getTime();// avoid cache
  },10000);// reload every 10 secs
}
```